# How can I add multiple emails to a user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple user model. In the update area, I wish for the user to be able to add as many emails as they like.

What is a neater and easier way to do it? Should it be made into an array? If so how can I customize the view? What should I use?

Thanks

Any guidance or help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main email is usually used as primary identification of an user, and usually need unique validation. Don't touch it.

If not too much emails to add and the action is not frequent, you can add an extra field say "alternative_emails" with string type.

When adding, add a space before email

```
alternative_emails += " #{new_email}"
```

When using, split it

```
alternative_emails.split(" ").each { |email| email.send }
```

Comment: how do I accepte the email from the user and save it to the db? I know I could either use by spacing them or create an additional field like `alternative_emails ` and serialize it (arrays). But like I said, how do I save it to the db?

Comment: It's simple an attribute of User model, just update this attr when you adding emails.

Comment: Why, in your case, not serializing it as Array (of strings)? an attribute extra_emails with type (Ruby) Array

Comment: Yep thats what I am asking :). I can access the params in the update method of the controller with `tmp = params[:user]` , then I can access the email with `tmp["alternative_emails"] ` but how do I append the new email to it?

Comment: @MrYoshiji yep it thought of doing it but not sure how to append the emails.

Comment: `@user.extra_emails.push("new@email.com")`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, the data is going to be saved in db so I set it as String.

Comment: @psharma, thanks for your accepting the answer. Just a reminder, this method only applies to very simple use case. For anything a bit fancier it's better to use model.

Comment: @BillyChan yep, even I am thinking so. Let me try few use cases. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard approach would be to have a new model called Email, and set up associations so that a user has many emails. So, you'd have something like:

```
class User
  has_many :emails
end

class Email
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: well is there another option than this? I kind of feel this is an overkill.

Comment: I know it may feel like overkill, since your email model will currently have just one attribute (for now), saving multiple emails in one attribute in the user model will come back to bite you. It will become extremely difficult to search for a user based on their emails. Having emails as a separate model will allow for easy querying for the future.